# oracle insert on subselect gives ORA-00936

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert into a table, whose values are same except few from the same table with max sequnce number based on an ID.

```
insert into ENT_ROLE_USERS_HISTORY(APP_ID,ROLE_ID,TAXID,CREATE_DT,CREATED_BY,STATUS,HIST_ID,ADD_DELETE) 
values(
select app_id, role_id, taxid, sysdate, 1233423123, 0, ent_role_us_hist_seq.nextval, 0 from (
select app_id, role_id, taxid from ENT_ROLE_USERS_HISTORY where app_id = 203 and TAXID = 13242342346 order by hist_id desc) where rownum = 1);
```

I execute the inner select and it works fine and gives me the record but the query fails for the insert. I am getting ORA-00936: missing expression.
Can someone let me know whats wrong or is there any other best way to do the same please?

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into ENT_ROLE_USERS_HISTORY(APP_ID,ROLE_ID,TAXID,CREATE_DT,CREATED_BY,STATUS,HIST_ID,ADD_DELETE) 
select app_id, role_id, taxid, sysdate, 1233423123, 0, ent_role_us_hist_seq.nextval, 0 from 
 (
     select app_id, role_id, taxid from ENT_ROLE_USERS_HISTORY 
        where app_id = 203 and TAXID = 13242342346 order by hist_id desc
  ) where rownum = 1
```